# The metric function returned error result: tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training my model using Keras, here is my code:

```
    model = keras.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Dense(len(COLUMN_NAMES), activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, use_bias=True),
      keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      keras.layers.Dense(split_num, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
          loss=focal_loss(gamma=2, alpha=0.85714),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train.values, y_train.values, epochs=5, batch_size=2000, verbose=1)
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test.values, y_test.values)
```

My y_test has 0:85%; 1:15%, It's output:

```
    32321/32321 [==============================] - 1s 40us/sample - loss: 0.0608 - acc: 1.0000
```

But when I checked it using:`predictions = model.predict(x_test.values, verbose=1)`, it predicted nearly all cases to 0. So, in my opinion the ['accuracy'] could be 85% instead of "acc: 1.0000". What's going wrong ?

Comment: How many samples does y_test have? Where does y_test have 85% ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several things you are confused about here:

- Firstly, `"acc: 1.0000"` indicates an accuracy of `1.0` which is equivalent to `100%`.
- Secondly, it is the accuracy on your training data, so it doesn't necessarily relate to the accuracy on your test data. Several things might have gone wrong. You may be overfitting because the model you are using is too big compared to the amount of available training data. You may also be fitting something that doesn't have the same distribution, i.e. `y_train` is all 0s. We can't help you further if you don't specify more what your data is

Comment: Firstly, I know **1.0** means **100%**, I think it must be **0.85**.  
Secondly, **"acc: 1.0000"** is the output base on my test data **x_test/y_test**, not on the train data **x_train/y_train**.

Comment: Why do you think it should be 85% on your training data?
From what I see, it looks that 100% accuracy is on your training data (printed output of `model.fit`).
However I don't see the output of `model.evaluate`.

Comment: Because I put `print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)` after `model.evaluate`,  the output is `32321/32321 [=======] - 1s 31us/sample - loss: 0.0604 - acc: 1.0000`  
`Test accuracy: 1.0`

Comment: Ah ok! you hadn't put it in your question so it was difficult for me to see that, next time try to put all the relevant information in there. Try to put in a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help further.
Also what are the exact proprtions of 1s and 0s in `predictions`?